# malloc and array in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C, and C is my first programming language. I'll add code first.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int row = 3, col = 2;

    int(*ptr)[2] = (int(*)[2])malloc(sizeof(int) * row * col);
    if (!ptr) exit(1);
    printf("%d", sizeof(*ptr[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

> 4

Maybe, `ptr[0]` is pointer or array. Should I think `ptr[0]` as  an array?

Comment: In C, `int(*ptr)[2] = (int(*)[2])malloc(sizeof(int) * row * col);` better as `int(*ptr)[2] = malloc(sizeof *ptr * row);` and `printf("%d", sizeof(*ptr[0]));` as `printf("%zu", sizeof *ptr[0]);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int (*ptr)[2]` declares `ptr` to be a pointer to an array of two `int`.

That means `*ptr` is an array of two `int`. `ptr[0]` is effectively the same as `*ptr`, so it is also an array of two `int`.

By definition, `ptr[0]` means to add zero to `ptr` and then apply `*`. Adding zero does not change the value, so `ptr[0]` is effectively `*ptr`.

Setting `ptr` to `(int (*)[2]) malloc(sizeof(int) * row * col);` sets it to point to memory that can be used as 3 arrays of 2 `int` (because `row` is 3 and `col` is 2). So those three arrays are `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]`, and `ptr[2]`.

Since each of those is an array of two `int`, they each have two elements, which can be accessed as `ptr[0][0]`, `ptr[0][1]`, `ptr[1][0]`, `ptr[1][1]`, `ptr[2][0]`, and `ptr[2][1]`.

Note that the subscript operator, `[ … ]`, can be used with pointers or arrays. In either case, `E1[E2]` is defined to be `*((E1) + (E2))`. With a pointer, this addition  operates in units of the pointed-to type. When `E1` is a pointer to an array of two `int`, adding 1 or 2 produces a pointer that points 1 or 2 arrays of two `int` further along in memory (as long as the arithmetic remains in bounds of the applicable space). When `E1` is an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, and then the arithmetic proceeds as for a pointer.